# Was there a reincarnation (as opposed to a ghola) of Baron Harkonnen in any Dune book?

Tags: dune

From https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1056/976:

> questions about the reincarnation of Baron Harkonnen in the Dune saga would be entirely on topic

Was there actually a **reincarnation** (as opposed to a ghola) of Baron Harkonnen in any of the Dune books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The genetic memory of the Baron overwhelmed and corrupted Alia, as her *in utero* exposure to the Waters of Life opened her genetic memory before she had learned enough Bene Gesserit training to protect herself adequately.

I wouldn't call this an actual reincarnation, but there are parallels in the concept, as the personality of the Baron became increasingly dominant.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't read the Dune books by Frank's child, but in the original 6 Dune book saga, the Baron was never reincarnated.  His influence corrupted Alia, but that's the extent of him being reincarnated.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alia_Atreides#Hunters_of_Dune), there was a Baron ghola, but your question specifically excludes gholas.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "reincarnation as opposed to a ghola"?  In the Dune universe there is the "other memory" of the Bene Gesserit, and there are gholas

> whose memories can be restored under some extreme circumstances (which IMHO makes no sense scientifically).

I would say a ghola is the closest thing to reincarnation in the Dune universe.

> And yes, there is a ghola of the Baron in the Hunters of Dune by Brian Herbert, not in any of the original books by Frank Herbert.

Comment: I was merely quoting Beofett's comment. I was assuming standard Wiki definition: `Reincarnation best describes the concept where the soul or spirit, after the death of the body, is believed to return to live in a new human body`

Comment: @DVK: sorry, I didn't click on the meta-discussion, so I missed the context.  I guess your question really is "should the corruption of Alia by Baron's memories count as reincarnation," right? In that case I would still say that a ghola is a better fit to the definition of reincarnation.